# OAuth 2.0 usando PHP

Tags: php, oauth2

Me estan solicitando hacer una API en php, ya lo tengo, pero me dicen que le implemente OAuth 2.0.

Estuve siguiendo un tutorial pero me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe a que se debe esto? o de que otra forma lo podría implementar?

Comment: Clickea en el enlace "detalles del error" para ver que te dice

Comment: *"que le implemente OAuth 2.0"* es una descripción sumamente vaga.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea porque tu $clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUri no se encuentran correctos o el correo que utilizas no se encuentra autorizado..

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).